# List with button error: I would a button every 8 elements of the list

Tags: javascript, android, list, button, view

I made an app that reads and shows data from an XML file. I want to show a button dynamically every 8 elements in this list. In my implementation the app show me a button for each element (including title). Somebody can help me? Thanks.
This is the code of my class (that recalls another class to pick data from xml file) with the class that generate a button for each element:

```
package com.example.giacomob.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Giacomo B on 05/08/2015.
 */
public class Page1 extends Activity {
   // private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    final int n_campi = 8; //definisco la costante del numero di campi per fermata
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page1);

        // String dato1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("NomeDati1");
        //Intent intent = getIntent(); // Point 1
        // Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); // Point 2
        // String data1 = bundle.getString("NomeDati1"); // Point 3
        String dato1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("NomeDati1"); //preleva la stringa
        Toast.makeText(this, dato1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //PROVA: questo mi fa comparire una specie di label notifica trasparente con il valore di "data1"
        Log.d("TAG", "data1:" + dato1); //credo sia una specie di debug

        // seconda stringa
        String destination_nf =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("Destinazione_scelta");
        String destination_f = destination_nf.trim(); //tolgo gli spazi a inzio e fine
        String destination = destination_f.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + destination_f.substring(1,destination_f.length()).toLowerCase(); //Faccio in modo che l'utente mi passi una stringa con prima maiuscola e le altre minuscole
        Toast.makeText(this, destination, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        //    String salve =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("ciao");

        int c=0, j=0, n=0;
        boolean verify = false;

        //FARE CONTROLLO IN CASO IL FILE XML E' VUOTO E QUINDI LA STRINGA E' VUOTA
        String[] arr = dato1.split("\\|");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " => " + arr[i]);
        }
        final ArrayList<String> listp = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=3; i<arr.length-1; i=i+n_campi) {

            if(arr[i].equals(destination)) {
                System.out.println(i + " des " + arr[i]);
                for(; j<n_campi+c; j++)
                    if(j==0+c) {
                        n++;
                        listp.add("Informazioni fermata numero " +n);
                        listp.add("Coordinata X: " + arr[j]);
                    }
                    else if(j==1+c)
                        listp.add("Coordinata Y: " + arr[j]);
                    else if (j==2+c)
                        listp.add("Nazione di destinazione: " + arr[j]);
                    else if (j==3+c)
                        listp.add("Paese di destinazione: " + arr[j]);
                    else if (j==4+c)
                        listp.add("Via di destinazione: " + arr[j]);
                    else if (j==5+c)
                        listp.add("Id Corriera: " + arr[j]);
                    else if (j==6+c)
                        listp.add("Paese Fermata: " + arr[j]);
                    else if (j==7+c) {
                        listp.add("Via fermata: " + arr[j]);
                        listp.add("   ");
                    }

                    verify = true;

            }
            else
            {
                j=j+n_campi;
            }

            c = j;
        }
        if(verify == false)
            Toast.makeText(this,"Non sono stati trovati mezzi per " + destination, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        final ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);



        mylist.setAdapter(new MyListAdaper(this, R.layout.activity_page1, listp));


        Button b_load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send2);
        b_load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent openTrack = new Intent(Page1.this, Track.class);

                //String ciao = "ahahah";
                //String data1 = ReadXMLFile.readXMLFile(Page1.this);
                openTrack.putExtra("Destination", getIntent().getExtras().getString("NomeDati1"));
                startActivity(openTrack);

            }
        });

    }

    private class MyListAdaper extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private int layout;



        public MyListAdaper(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            layout = resource;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder mainViewHolder = null;
            if(convertView == null ){
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
               // viewHolder.thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_thumbnail)
             //tolto   viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prova);
                viewHolder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_btn);
                viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                     Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Bottone cliccato" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        }

                                                     });
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else {
                mainViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
             //tolto  mainViewHolder.title.setText(getItem(position));
            }

            return convertView;
        }

    }
    public class ViewHolder {
        //ImageView  thumbnail; //forse non serve
       // TextView title;
        Button button;
    }
    }
```

this is the activity code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/string_destination"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/prova"
        android:id="@+id/prova"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="359dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textList"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/list_item_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        />



    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/string_loadfermata"
        android:id="@+id/button_send2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please, help me

this is an example image:

[image]

Comment: That is a lot of code. What have you tried to do to show the button every 8 elements, and why/how does it not work? Have a look at "[*how do I ask a good question*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set visibility for your button
 `yourButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);`
where you don't need it.

Or set `visibility='GONE'` in list item xml and set `yourButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` for each 8 element.

Comment: you can give me an example? please

Comment: I have two XML files: one XML file contains data pick from this class, another XML file contain tha Activity of this class. Can I come to set the button EVERY 8 ?

Comment: You need to put 'if(position % 8 == 0) {
                    viewHolder.button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    viewHolder.button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                ' to your getView method in MyListAdaper clas

Comment: Because % is Remainder operator. You need button in each 8 element. position % 8 == 0 will be true in cases, where position =8,16,24,32,40 and more.

Comment: ok thanks. But there are a mistake in my code: only two position that repeat: 0 and 1..why?

Comment: Are you sure that you have more than 2 elements in your 'listp' ArrayList?

Comment: yes!! in fact the other elements of the list appens

Comment: What does listp.size() return?

Comment: It's strange! I have placed a System.out.println to show me the position in the logcat, in my getView class. There are also a tast for each button that should show the position... the toast show only 0 or 1, but the System.out.println show the real position!!!

Comment: Ok, the position is true on the top of the class getView. But, in  "viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()" the position is 0 or 1..why?

Comment: and in the middle, position appears only one time with 0 and 1

Comment: I'm sorry for all these comments, but the problem is on the "if". I delete this if and the button works...but it doesnt' show the element of the listp in this way

Comment: Your buttons appear in each 8 button? If yes, could you mark my answer as right answer?

Comment: probablu, the mistake is here: 
viewHolder.title  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
aren't TextView, but a Listview